# Level Ancestor Query long-paths algorithm complexity of sqrt n

Tags: complexity-theory, theory

Can someone explain why the complexity of a query for LA is √n when we only decompose the tree into long-paths? How can we show/prove that?

How can we prove that the **number of paths can be as high as O(√n)** ??? Please help, I've been struggling for a couple of days now.

Stage 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_ancestor_problem#Naive_methods

**Long-path decomposition of a Tree**

[image]

This is a recursive method that decomposes a given tree into paths. This stages starts off by finding the longest root-to-leaf path in the tree. It then removes this path by breaking its ties from the tree which will break the remaining of the tree into sub-trees and then it recursively processes each sub-tree. Every time a path is decomposed, an array is created in association with the path that contains the elements on the path from the root to the leaf. The base case of this recursion is when the tree is a path in which case its removal leaves an empty graph. Each vertex v has a unique ladder which is the ladder containing it and we call it the "v's ladder". However, after this pre-processing stage, the queries cannot be answered quickly. In fact in order to answer a level ancestor query, the algorithm needs to jump from a path to another until it reaches the root and there could be Θ(√n) of such paths on a leaf-to-root path. This leads us to an algorithm that can pre-process the tree in O(n) time and answers queries in O(√n). In order to reach the optimal query time.

I only need to know how to show that the number of paths can be O(√n) in the worst case.